# How to leave and delete an organisation so that I only have a personal login option available in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

My Teams app currently shows two login options - one for personal and one for an organisation I setup. My goal is to leave and delete the organisation so that I only have the personal login option available.

To do this I have followed these steps:

1. I login into my account, navigate to the ***Organisations*** section and click ***Leave*** next to the one I don’t want to be associated with anymore.
2. I am warned that leaving will result in the deletion of my data and continue by clicking another ***Leave*** button.
3. I am then presented with this message:

> You can't leave this tenant because you are the last admin in this
> organization (tenant), you’re not allowed to leave it. You’ll need to
> delete this tenant instead. Learn more

4. I proceed to delete the tenant in Azure Active Directory using the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-delete-howto).
5. Finally, I reach the point where checks are made before deletion and I receive the following message along with an indication that I have failed the check for active license based subscriptions (as shown in the image).

> We have detected that your current user account is external to this
> tenant. Please sign-out and login with Global Admin credentials using
> the initial default domain name such as user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com.

[image]

These issues confuse me because I do not know what credentials to log in with and I can’t find any licenses being shown as active after checking (although there are Microsoft Teams (free) and Microsoft Teams Essentials in the list of licenses with no users).

Perhaps someone could ask me some questions to get to the bottom of these issues and help me arrive at the point when I can delete the organisation and simplify my Teams setup?

Comment: For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online).

For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).